# Como inicializar una interface que contiene otras interfaces desde un componente en Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

Estoy haciendo un llamado a firebase con un servicio el cual me retorna una json, el cual eh modelado en interface para poder acceder a sus datos, la interfaz se ve de la siguiente manera:

```
export interface Restaurante {
  footer: Footer;
  logo: string;
  section_1: Section1;
  section_2: Section2;
  slide_header: Slide[];
}

export interface Footer {
  contacto: Contacto;
  logo_footer: string;
  redes: Redes;
}

export interface Contacto {
  direccion: string;
  mail: string;
  telefono: string;
}

export interface Redes {
  facebook: string;
  instagram: string;
}

export interface Section1 {
  slide_promo: Slide[];
}

export interface Slide {
  img: string;
}

export interface Section2 {
  type_menu: TypeMenu[];
}

export interface TypeMenu {
  menu: Menu[];
  type: string;
}

export interface Menu {
  description: string;
  img: string;
  price: string;
  title: string;
}
```

A la interfaz de contacto logre acceder inicializado la interfaz de manera completa, pero mi problema se da al momento de tener que acceder a los datos que viene de footer que esta dentro de otra interfaz y a su vez contiene otras interfazes.

```
datos: Contacto = {
    direccion: 'string',
    mail: 'string',
    telefono: 'string',
  }; 
  constructor(private firebase: FirebaseService) {
    this.firebase.datosHeader().subscribe(
      (datos) => {
        this.datos = datos.footer.contacto;
      },
      (err) => {}
    );
    console.log(this.datos);
  }
```

Cuando lo realizo de la siguiente manera me da error, por lo que me gustaria saber como puedo acceder a la información que viene dentro de footer.

```
datos!: Footer;
  /* datos: Contacto = {
    direccion: 'string',
    mail: 'string',
    telefono: 'string',
  };  */
  constructor(private firebase: FirebaseService) {
    this.firebase.datosHeader().subscribe(
      (datos) => {
        this.datos = datos.footer;
      },
      (err) => {}
    );
    console.log(this.datos);
  }
```

Comment: ¿Y cuál es el error?

Comment: No puedo acceder a los datos dentro de Restaurante desde el componente.

Answer (score 0):

Para inicializar una interfaz puedes realizarlo de la siguiente manera:

```
let foot = {} as Footer;
```

Comment: Por favor, agrega más detalles para ampliar tu respuesta, como código que funcione o citas de documentación.